# linux system command mail - the GUI client?

Tags: linux, email, client, command, system

Have anyone of you ever heard about some `KDE` or `GNOME` (GUI in general) application that can read system mail in Linux?

Using `mail` command or browsing the `/var/mail/root` files seems very inconvenient.

Comment: Not really a programming question. Would probably fit better on [superuser.se](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: More a sysad question, but anyhow I think you have two options. Use a graphical MUI like thunderbird or kmail to import the mbox stored in `/var/mail/root` or install a pretty lightweight local mail server (IMAP should be way to go). Depends on your distribution, but on most systems the second way most likely is a task of a couple of seconds.

Comment: Or just alias (adding an entry in `/etc/aliases`) the root and other system users to some significant (human) user.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch solution is what I've seen everywhere for as long I've been using Unix systems. Mails to root and other system accounts are forwarded to a list of human beings.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should not use the root account to read the messages. Instead, forward the mail to your normal account or external email address.

The forwarding can be done in the mail server configuration, or more easily by creating a file `/root/.forward` with your e-mail address (and nothing else) in it.

Delivering to external addresses requires that you have configured an SMTP server to use; you can test if it works by sending a message with `mail myaddress@example.com`.

Comment: This does not answer the question about GUI clients. How to configure them to read local account mail?

Comment: @user2513149 Yeah, there are better answers e.g. here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird